# How to create XLSX file from LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, excel

I am using the below code to create XLS from LWC component but if i change `XLS` to `XLSX` the excel generated is invalid. Any inputs on how to create XLSX will be helpful

```
contactDataz = [{
        "OrderNum":"000921",
        "OrderDate": "01/02/2023",
        "OrderStatus": "Pending",
        "OrderItemCount": "3",
    }];
    columnHeader = ['Order Num', 'Order Date', 'Order Status', 'Order Item Count' ];  

 let doc = '<table>';
        // Add all the Table Headers
        doc += '<tr>';
        this.columnHeader.forEach(element => {
            doc += '<th>' + element + '</th>'
        });
        doc += '</tr>';
        // Add the data rows
        this.contactDataz.forEach(record => {
            doc += '<tr>';
            doc += '<th>' + record.OrderNum + '</th>';
            doc += '<th>' + record.OrderDate + '</th>';
            doc += '<th>' + record.OrderStatus + '</th>';
            doc += '<th>' + record.Email + '</th>';
            doc += '</tr>';
        });
        doc += '</table>';
        
        //for CSV use data:text/csv;charset=utf-8
        //for XLS use data:application/vnd.ms-excel
        
        var element = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(doc);
        let downloadElement = document.createElement('a');
        downloadElement.href = element;
        downloadElement.target = '_self';
        // use .csv as extension on below line if you want to export data as csv
        downloadElement.download = 'OrderData.xls'; //OrderData.csv
        document.body.appendChild(downloadElement);
        downloadElement.click();
```

Comment: try [sheetjs](https://sheetjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Change the `application/vnd.ms-excel` to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`